# How do iOS animation blocks work?

Tags: ios, core-animation, objective-c-blocks

In iOS, you can [animate view objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html) using animation blocks:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

        firstView.alpha = 0.0;

        secondView.alpha = 1.0;

}];
```

What we have here is a code block that describes what the view properties will end up looking after the animation is finished.

How does this work?

I could understand (I think) if this was done using some declarative format, but from the looks of it, the animation block is just a regular piece of code that presumably has to be executed, the results inspected and then someone transcoded into the actual lower-level graphics code that performs the animation.

Is the block actually executed (or somehow reverse-engineered) and if so, when?

If this code is executed before the animation starts, then how come the changes to the referenced view properties are not reflected immediately?

What happens if I put code in the block that does not change view properties, but does something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the block is actually invoked -- then it changes the view's properties immediately. The  UIView's property setters are responsible to see if the set was used within an animation context -- if so, they calculate the animation frames etc. using CoreAnimation and CoreGraphics.

If you put non-animation code into these blocks, nothing special will happen -- the block will be executed immediately.

Comment: Aha! So inside of UIView, there is code that inspects the call stack and if it is called from a animation block, it does something entirely different than just updating itself directly?

Comment: I'm not sure it inspects the call stack; it should rather be the animation methods that set up some kind of internal context.

Comment: Aha! But then the UIView checks this context and acts accordingly?

Comment: What happens if I call the same property twice in the same block? Or conflicting properties? Say `firstView.alpha = 0.0; firstView.alpha = 0.25;` Do they get queued? Or overwrite each-other?

Comment: No conflict: the latter will be the effective, the former gets discarded.

Answer (score 6):

It is instructive to look at the equivalent code prior to blocks:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"foo" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
firstView.alpha = 0.0;
secondView.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

So you see, even before blocks, the properties to change are also set directly; however, they do not take effect immediately (they are animated).

How does it work? Presumably when you set a property on the view, it checks to see if you're run `beginAnimations` but not `commitAnimations`, and does not take effect immediately if it is (but rather adds it to the list of things to animate for that animation).

So what the blocks version does is very simple in the context of the pre-blocks version: you can just think of it as running the animation block inside `beginAnimations` and `commitAnimations` lines.

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't really talk about the nitty-gritty details of how it works, but here's what I think happens:

The system adds KVO observers on all the animatable properties of a view when the view is added to the view hierarchy.

When your animation block executes, the system sets a state that watches for KVO notifications on those properties. The code that gets invoked then creates and adds the appropriate CAAnimation objects to each affected view's layer.

Comment: That would separate the animation code from the View implementation nicely. Is it possible for the KVO observer to suppress setting the property (and instead queue animations)? Also, while Apple does not talk about this, is there a way to inspect/instrument a running system to see what happens?

Comment: You don't need to suppress setting the property. Core Animation is done by displaying a presentation layer, which is independent from the actual settings of the layer. In fact, with CAAnimation objects, one of the ways to animate a change is to set a layer's property without animation, then submit a CAAnimation that animates that change. Once the animation is complete it is removed and the layer is rendered at it's final state. If you submit a CAAnimation without changing the underlying property, the layer snaps back to it's original state once the animation completes.